# Where should i store data in vue js? (vuex, localstorage)

Tags: vue.js, web, vuejs2, vuex

For example: if we have user data (username, fullname) and we use it in our components where should we store this: vuex or localstorage?

Comment: Quite possibly both. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist

Answer (score 3):

Vuex store is used to maintain the current state of your application, whereas local storage is used as a persistent state.

I would only want to save usernames and full names of my users while they are using the application as those are personal details and shouldn't be accessible while not being logged in. Especially for public computers this would be a privacy concern.